# How would I execute this query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

Let's say I have a collection of "rooms". Each room is a document that looks like this:

```
room = {
        perms: [ { user:"matt", visible: 1 },
                 { user:"alex", visible: 0 },
                 { user:"jennifer", visible: 1 },
};
```

In MongoDB, how would I find rooms that have a permission of `user=alex and visible=0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the $elemMatch operator should do what you want:

```
{ "perms": { "$elemMatch": { "user": "alex", "visible": 0 } } }
```